# IIS Connection Pool interrogation/leak tracking

Tags: iis, ado, connection-pooling

Per this [helpful article](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/040830.htm) I have confirmed I have a connection pool leak in some application on my IIS 6 server running W2k3.

The tough part is that I'm serving 300 websites written by 700 developers from this server in 6 application pools, 50% of which are .NET 1.1 which doesn't even show connections in the CLR Data performance counter. I could watch connections grow on my end if everything were .NET 2.0+, but I'm even out of luck on that slim monitoring tool.

My 300 websites connect to probably 100+ databases spread out between Oracle, SQLServer and outliers, so I cannot watch the connections from the database end either.

Right now my best and only plan is to do a loose binary search for my worst offenders. I will kill application pools and slowly remove applications from them until I find which individual applications result in the most connections dropping when I kill their pool. But since this is a production box and I like continued employment, this could take weeks as a tracing method.

Does anyone know of a way to interrogate the IIS connection pools to learn their origin or owner? Is there an MSMQ trigger I might be able to which I might be able to attach when they are created? Anything silly I'm overlooking?

Kevin

(I'll include the error code to facilitate others finding your answers through search:
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try starting with this [first article from Bill Vaughn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175863(SQL.80).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Todd Denlinger wrote a fantastic class http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/connectionmonitor.aspx which watches Sql Server connections and reports on ones that have not been properly disposed within a period of time. Wire it into your site, and it will let you know when there is a leak.